# Mozilla Firefox Quantum: Some websites don't open

Tags: firefox, websites

I am using Firefox Quantum and I am not able to open/use some websites. For example, take https://www.sbiyono.sbi/.

When I click on login, it shows this: [image]

Pl help.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you already try visiting that site with add-ons disabled? It works fine for me.

Comment: @pomsky, I tried in normal window, still the problem persists.

Comment: @ByteCommander, I disabled all add-ons, .... not helpful.

Comment: Are you sure that that site has anything to do with the State Bank of India? I don't think it's an "official" site. Personally, I'd stay away from it.

Comment: On looking at the site it bit more, I'm not  sure it's a "fake" site. All the same, check with the bank itself.

Comment: @DKBose, I have been using it before.... since some months. Site is not fake.

Comment: I seem to be able to get to the pre-login page, https://www.sbiyono.sbi/wps/portal/login#!/prelogin, which has fields for username and password. This is with Firefox 63. Have you tried *safe mode* or a new profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it in the following way:

1. Opened **about:config**.
2. Searched **network.http.sendRefererHeader**
3. Put the value to 2 (mine was 0).

Credit goes to my friend who was brave enough to allow me to read his about:config file... and that's it.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: And `2` is the default.